# Can the Vboxfs mount point be formatted?

Tags: virtualbox, centos, vagrant, fsck

As I am working on the Oracle XE 11g database installation on virtualbox guest os: CentOS 7. Installed all the prerequisite libraries. when I have run the rpm command it is not able to execute that due to disk issue. I am trying to install in the shared folder /u01/app/software contains binaries. path to install is /u01/app/oracle.

```
[root@localhost Disk1]# rpm -ivh oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
        installing package oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64 needs 2179 inodes on the /u01/app/oracle filesystem
```

FYI, the filesystem my vm is ...

```
[root@localhost Disk1]# df -hT
Filesystem              Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root xfs       8.4G  3.9G  4.5G  47% /
devtmpfs                devtmpfs  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   tmpfs     3.9G  8.3M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                   tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1               xfs       497M  102M  396M  21% /boot
none                    vboxsf    924G  194G  730G  21% /vagrant
none                    vboxsf    924G  194G  730G  21% /u01/app/oracle
none                    vboxsf    924G  194G  730G  21% /u01/app/software
```

Do I need to format the shared folder? 
VirtualBox that is running based on Vagrant might have limited scope.
any best alternatives to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've two problems. the existing XE is not able to work. When it works the shared folder of VirtualBox disabled.

1. After a while I got a thought to remove the installed Oracle XE 11g from the box using

> yum remove oracle-xe

This would delete the improper installation of Oracle XE.

The shared folder can be visible if you use virtualbox manage command.

2. Shared folder can be re appear if you do

> vagrant reload

still I wish to listen from the experts view.
.